# Is somebody no ones cousin or is somebody not a cousin to everybody?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am given the following first order sentence:

$\exists x \forall y(\neg Cousin(x, y))$

Note that the predicate Cousin(x, y) means *"x and y are cousins"*.

I am asked to provide an English translation to this statement. My approach is to first go about interpreting the statement without the negation, that is:
$\exists x \forall y(Cousin(x, y))$
 which would give me:

> There exists someone that is a cousin to everyone.

I then add the negation as per the beginning of the question which gives me:

> There exists someone that is not a cousin to everyone.

However, upon looking at the solution I see that the correct interpretation is:

> **Somebody is no ones cousin**

Could someone explain to me in an intuitive way why and where my interpretation fell short of the answer?

Comment: $\exists x\forall y (\neg Cousin(x,y))$ iff (There exists x, such that $\forall y, (\neg Cousin(x,y)$ iff (There exists x such that for every $y$, $\neg Cousin(x,y)$ iff (There exists x such that for every y, x is not y's cousin) iff somebody is no one's cousin.

Comment: "There exists someone that is not a cousin to everyone." is equivalent to $\exists x \lnot \forall y(\text{Cousin}(x,y))$, but not $\exists x  \forall y(\lnot \text{Cousin}(x,y))$

Comment: I would have phrased it "There exists someone that is not a cousin to *any*one."  That said, it seems that what you are having difficulty with is the English rather than the math.  What the statement is saying is that we can find some person such that among his relatives there are no cousins.  This is different than saying that we can find some person such that we can find at least one other person that he is not a cousin of.

Comment: No, @JMoravitz. By removing the negation from the middle of the logical statement and then adding it back *in front*, OP is definitely making a mathematical error and not an English one.

Comment: @Nelver Interesting. Thats a subtelty I wouldnt have picked up, thanks. I guess ill just have to practice more to get into identifying the difference between the two.

Comment: @Nelver I think $\exists x\neg(\forall y\text{Cousin}(x,y))\equiv \exists x\exists y \neg \text{Cousin}(x,y)$ that is at least two people that not cousin to each other

Comment: @Dean P what's the difference between the one you write "There exists someone that is not a cousin to everyone" and "Somebody is no ones cousin", it sounds same to me

Comment: @Manx Suppose the domain of discourse includes John, James, Gary and Kevin. The former says that someone, say John, is not a cousin to everyone, i,e. John is not a cousin to James and Gary and Kevin at the same time. The latter says that someone, again, say, John, doesnt have a cousin.

Comment: I think John doesn't have a cousin implies john is not a cousin to everyone, and also the converse, they should be equivalent.

Comment: The $\exists x\forall y (\lnot K(a,y))$ is not the negation of $\exists x\forall y (K(a,y))$.

Comment: "By removing the negation from the middle of the logical statement and then adding it back in front, OP is definitely making a mathematical error and not an English one. "  DEFINITELY.  $\forall y(\lnot K(y))$ means every $y$ doesn't K (example "every rabbit doesn't eat meat" [apparantly true]  or "every bird doesn't fly" [clearly false]) and $\lnot \forall y(K(y))$ means not every $y$ does K (example "not ever rabbit eats meat" [but some maybe do?] or "not every bird flies" [well, yes, that's true...]).  Completely different statements!

Comment: "I think John doesn't have a cousin implies john is not a cousin to everyone, and also the converse, they should be equivalent." But they aren't!   John is not a cousin to everybody doesn't mean John doesn't have a cousin!  Suppose John is *not* the cousin of Pope Francis, Arnold Schwarzeneger, or Trevon Martin.  Then John is not a cousin to everyone.  Does that mean John doesnt have a cousin.  I don't know about John but *I* have a cousin.  And I am *NOT* a cousin to everyone.  ... I pretty much doubt *anyone* is a cousin to Pope Francis, Arnold Schwarzenegger *AND* Trevon Martin.

Comment: I might misunderstood the language, sorry about that everyone$\dots$ I'll ask that on english.stackexchange

Comment: kind of understand it now @fleablood, thanks

Comment: The english can be ambiguous. "not a cousin to everybody" could be taken to mean either "for every person, he's not their cousin" (i.e. he has no cousin) or "it's not true the everybody is his cousin" (i.e. he could have some cousins but there is at least one person who isn't). So the language is amiguous but the logic is *not*.  $\forall y(\lnot cousins(x,y))$ means no-one is his cousin. And $\lnot\forall y(cousins(x,y))$ means it is not the case that everyone is his cousin.  Don't worry about language. But *do* worry about logic.

Answer (score 2):

> > There exists someone that is not a cousin to everyone.
>
> However, upon looking at the solution I see that the correct interpretation is:
>
> > Somebody is no ones cousin

You are not wrong, because those are equivalent claims.   The second is just abbreviated better.

They both say: "There is someone who is no*t-any*one's cousin."
$$\def\Cousin{\operatorname{Cousin}}\exists x~\forall y~\neg\Cousin(x,y)\quad\iff\quad\exists x~\neg\exists y~\Cousin(x,y)$$

---

It can also be restated as: "Not everyone has a cousin."

$$\neg \forall x~\exists y~\Cousin(x,y)$$

Answer (score 1):

As I've said in the comments, your interpretation actually corresponds to:

$$\exists x \lnot \forall y (\text{Cousin}(x,y))$$

Instead of what you are asked to translate

$$\exists x  \forall y (\lnot \text{Cousin}(x,y))$$

---

I will make a feeble attempt at providing "intuition":

Before trying to translate first-order logic into colloquial English, it might be better to use "basic" language first.

Let $F(x,y)$ be some statement

$\exists$ stands for "exists"

$\forall$ stands for "for all"

> $\exists x \forall y (F(x,y))$

Translates into: Exists at least one $x$ such that for all $y$ $F(x,y)$ is true.

> $\exists x \forall y (\lnot F(x,y))$

Translates into: Exists at least one $x$ such that for all $y$ $F(x,y)$ is false.

> $\exists x \lnot \forall y (F(x,y))$

Translates into: Exists at least one $x$ such that *not* for all $y$ $F(x,y)$ is true.

Clearly, "for all $y$ $F(x,y)$ is false" and "*not* for all $y$ $F(x,y)$ is true" are two different statements.

In your case you have

$$\exists x \forall y(\neg Cousin(x, y))$$

So again, using basic language first:

Exists $x$ such that for all $y$ statement $\text{Cousin}(x,y)$ is False.

To put it roughly:

> There is somebody ($\exists x$) such that everybody ($\forall y$) is not his cousin ($\lnot \text{Cousin}(x,y)$).

Which in proper English means

> Somebody is no ones cousin

---

Comment: I think $\exists x\neg(\forall y \text{Cousin}(x,y))$ is saying at least one pair of people isn't cousin to each other, which is different from his translation

Comment: @Manx, It is equivalent to his translation. If "at least one pair of people isn't cousin to each other", then we can take person $x$ and person $y$, such that $x$ is not cousin to $y$. Which means that there is at least one person that is not cousin to $x$, or in other words, $\exists x \exists y \lnot (\text{Cousin}(x,y)$), which is obviously equivalent to $\exists x \lnot \forall y (\text{Cousin}(x,y))$

Comment: His  translation is "There exists someone that is not a cousin to everyone.", which is exists someone say $x$ that to any $y$, they do not have that Cousin relationship, or write $\exists x\forall y,\neg \text{Cousin}(x,y)$, which is obviously different to $∃x¬∀y(\text{Cousin}(x,y)) $

Comment: @Manx, it seems that you think statements "There exists someone that is not a cousin to everyone." and "Somebody is no ones cousin" are equivalent. **They are not.** MSE is not about English language, so if you disagree with me, I would advise you to ask this question on https://english.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @ Nelver ah$\dots$ seems like I misunderstood the language, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

> My approach is to first go about interpreting the statement without the negation ... I then add the negation as per the beginning of the question

But $\forall y (\lnot K)$ is not at all the same thing as $\lnot \forall y(K)$!

You *CAN'T* take out a negative in the center and put in front.  You should not have thought that you could.

Consider.  Then statement "Every bird cannot fly"  ($\forall b(\lnot fly(b))$) and "Not every bird can fly" ($\lnot (\forall b(fly(b))$.  The first is obviously false (doves can fly) and the second is obviously true (penguins can't).

Instead $\forall y(\lnot K)$ is $\not \exists y(K)$.  "For all things this doesn't happen" is "There is no thing where this does happen".

So in this case $\exists x \forall y(\lnot Cousins(x,y))$ is the same as $\exists x\not\exists y(Cousins (x,y)$.

Or "there exists a guy for whom everybody is not his cousin" is the same as "there exists a guy for whom no-one is his cousin" which is the same as "there is a guy who has no cousins".

Then statement $\exists x \lnot (\forall y(cousins(x,y))$ is saying there is a guy who is not everybody's cousin. (That could be anybody! Nobody is everybody's cousin because not every body shares cousins!)

$\lnot (\forall y K)$ is not the sames as $\forall y (\lnot K)$.  ("Not all birds fly" $\ne$ "All birds don't fly")  $\lnot (\forall y K)$ is $\exists y (\lnot K)$. ("Not all birds fly" $=$ "there is a bird that doesn't fly").

So had you begun with $\exists x \exists y(\lnot Cousins(x,y))$ *then* your interpretation would be correct $\exists x\lnot(\forall y (Cousins(x,Y))$.

"There exists a person who has a person who is not his cousin" is the same as "there exists a person who is not everybody's cousin".